# Apache alias/rewrite redirect loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, alias, infinite-loop

I want to use some aliases for my apache, using mod_rewrite, since alias doesn't work from `.htaccess`.

For example I want an Alias for `article/?id=1` to be `about/`

Sure, a simple thing does it:

```
RewriteRule ^about\/$ "article\/\?id=1" [L]
```

However, at the same time I don't want anyone to access `article/?id=1` anymore, and make a 301 redirect to `about/` to preserve the page value and the juice. (Because otherwise the search engine will think it's two different pages and will judge it on it's own discretion.)

So In other words I want this url to be only available by it's alias, and if someone requests the actual page - then 301 redirect to the alias.

And that's where the problem begins, as I write another rewrite rule, I end up with error 310 (redirect loop):

```
RewriteRule ^article\/\?id=1$ "about\/" [L,R=301]
```

Is there any way to solve this problem... ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to match against the actual request and not against the URI because the other rule will simply rewrite it internally and trigger the redirect, causing a loop. Also, you can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /article/\?id=1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /about/?%2 [L,R=301]
```